# Como agendar releases na integração contínua no Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, integração-contínua

Estou utilizando a ferramenta Jenkins para integração contínua, está funcionando normalmente. 
Tentei deixar agendado para fazer build a cada 3 horas, para isso assinalei o checkbox "Construir periodicamente" e deixei da seguinte maneira:

```
* 3 * * *
```

Deixar dessa maneira o mesmo gerou várias build durante às 03:00 e 04:00, alguém saberia me dizer qual o comando para deixar gerando build automático a cada 3 horas?

No próprio Jenkins ele dá o seguinte exemplo:

```
Exemplos    
# todo minuto
* * * * *
# no minuto 5 de cada hora (ou seja '2:05,3:05,...') 
5 * * * *
```

Tentei seguir essa lógica, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aparentemente o Jeninks está usando o [formato cron](http://www.devin.com.br/crontab/), comum em sistemas Linux. Desse modo, o que sua instrução está dizendo é: "execute a tarefa uma vez a cada minuto (`*`) da hora `3`, todo dia (`*`), todo mês (`*`), qualquer dia da semana (`*`)". Para que sua tarefa execute a cada 3 horas, uma maneira seria:

```
0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * *
```

Detalhando:

- `0` - a tarefa sempre irá executar no minuto zero (aceita `0-59`);
- `0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21` - a tarefa irá executar à zero hora, às três, às seis... (aceita `0-23`);
- `*` - a tarefa irá executar todo dia (aceita `1-31`);
- `*` - a tarefa irá executar todo mês (aceita `1-12`);
- `*` - a tarefa irá executar qualquer dia da semana (aceita `0-6`, onde `0` é "domingo").

Ou seja, você especifica em qual minuto da hora você quer que ele execute, e em quais horas. O resto você deixa como `*` (se aplica a todos). A segunda instrução (hora) pode ser simplificada dessa forma:

```
0 */3 * * *
```

Nesse caso o `*/3` significa "de três em três [horas]" - mas sem especificar qual a hora inicial. Nesse caso, não sei ao certo em que horários a tarefa iria executar, exceto que haverá um intervalo de 3 horas entre uma execução e outra.

Esse `*` pode também ser substituído por um intervalo explícito. Um exemplo mais complexo:

```
15 0-6/2 * * 0,3
```

"Todo domingo e toda quarta, de duas em duas horas às madrugadas, no minuto 15" Ou seja: `00:15`, `02:15`, `04:15` e `06:15` (repare que o intervalo é fechado).

---

<sub>**Nota:** essa resposta assume que o Jenkins implementa correta e completamente o formato Cron; caso apenas um **subconjunto** do mesmo seja suportado, algumas das opções acima podem não estar disponíveis. Sugiro que realize alguns testes para determinar se determinada instrução funciona como esperado.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

O padrão para repetir de 3 em 3 horas é: `H */3 * * *`.

Foi testado no Jenkins versão 1.612